# Wrong parameter passed in VB (Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, parameter-passing

I try to do a simple function call, with parameters as string, but one of the parameters is not passed. I just don't get it.

The function `GrafikUpdates` is called, with second parameter being a non empty-string:

```
GrafikUpdates("Optimal", oBHKWop.Modell, "Add")
```

[image: Calling the function]

The function is then executed, but with the second parameter being empty.

```
Public Sub GrafikUpdates(ByVal Modulgröße As String, ByVal Modultyp As String, _
                         ByVal AddOrRemove As String)
```

[image: Into the function]

What is going wrong?

Comment: Did you recompile before running this?

Comment: Tip: Since you're using VS 2010, install the service pack, then get rid of the `ByVal` keyword.

Comment: @Oded: Yes, I am every time starting a full debugging.

Comment: @Mr.Steak: SP1 is installed and my first try was without the `ByVal` keyword. I just thought I'd use it to better understand where the error comes from.

Comment: have you tried to to clean the solution from the build menu?

Comment: @03Usr: I tried just now. It ran successfully but did not give any output. I could not start the debugging after that though and needed to restart my machine: the vshost.exe was not accessible.

Comment: Solved! Well, kind of. Correcting a third function that is, to my knowledge, not used to call the function `GrafikUpdates` has solved the problem. I still don't get it though...